# Need to identify non contigious rows

Tags: postgresql-9.6, gaps-and-islands

My table structure is as follows:

```
create table daily_summary
(
    id                 uuid           default uuid_generate_v4() not null
            primary key,
    machine            bigint                                    not null
    odometer_start     numeric(10, 3)                            not null,
    odometer_end       numeric(10, 3)                            not null,
    distance           numeric(10, 3)                            not null,
    date               timestamp                                 not null,
    ...

);
```

The data in the daily_summary table should be contigious for a machine, ie the odometer_end for a row for a machine should be the odometer_start for the same machine in the next row when ordered by date.

Is there a query using lead() or any other way that I can use to identify non contigious row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select *
from (
  select ds.*,
         lag(ds.odometer_end) over (partition by ds.machine order by ds."date") as prev_end
  from daily_summary ds
) t
where odometer_start <> prev_end + 1  
order by "date"
```

Comment: Works exactly as what I wanted, thanks!